Internet goes offline after starting Asp.net project on Visual studio
I just moved to a new PC with Win11 and I'm facing this issue.
After I start this asp.net project in Visual studio internet stops working for some reason after few seconds, it uses IIS express to run in development mode on Localhost.
The project impersonates another user, so maybe that's the cause:
<identity impersonate="true" password="XXX" userName="mydomain\myuser"/>
The "UniversalTelemetryClient" in the Event log, logs:
Connection state - Some connections have failed since the previous period.
Which isn't very helpful, where else can I look for clues?
I have no reason to believe it is a project misconfiguration as it's running just fine on PCs with Win10, I guess it might be something wrong with some permission on My PC, something else related to Win11.
The ethernet driver is up to date.
I tried to run it on a different port, it doesn't make any difference.

Turns out it was a group policy problem, not sure why the same didn't happen on windows 10.
The solution is to allow internet access for the account that is impersonated.
